Expand \hbox to the width of parent \vbox
I have two \hboxes, one above another, inside \vbox:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Some\vbox{\hbox{longer text above}\hbox{shorter text}}and some more text.
\end{document}

Which produces:

Now I would like to fill remaining space in bottom \hbox (shorter text) with some kind of fill, for example \hrule:

How could I achieve that minimal width of bottom \hbox matches that of \vbox (which is determined by width of top \hbox) and could be thus filled with line, if it was shorter than top \hbox?
Notice that there should not be any added whitespace before and after \vbox. If I try like that
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Some\vbox{\hbox{longer text above}\hbox{shorter text\leaders\hrule\hfill\null}}and some more text.
\end{document}

there is no effect. It doesn't work, there is no rule added.
I assume that is because \hbox with shorter text is just wide enough for it's content, so there is nothing to fill.
I can try with some inline tabular:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Some\begin{tabular}[b]{l}longer text above\\shorter text\leaders\hrule\hfill\null\end{tabular}and 
    some more text.
\end{document}

Which adds rule but also adds some whitespace on left and right side:

Besides that, it seems to me that boxes are more right way to go, so I would prefer solution using them. I would also want to avoid any additional packages, since it seems to me, that this is something that shouldn't be that hard to achieve without them.
The whole \vbox thing is to be used inside a macro, so I don't know length of both rows (with rows I mean text inside \hboxes) in advance. I would like to avoid calculating widths of rows, because second \hbox and \vbox are actually closed by \egroup\egroup from one of the following commands.
How could I achieve that minimal width of bottom \hbox matches that of \vbox (which is determined by width of top \hbox) and could be thus filled with line, if it was shorter than top \hbox?

The task you are asking about is solved by \halign primitive. It was designed exactly for this purposes.
Some\vbox{\halign{#\hrulefill\cr longer text above\cr shorter text\cr}}
and some more text.

\bye


If there is no switch to horizontal mode, the \vbox is as wide as the widest \hbox in the vertical list and you could rebuild the \vbox after dismantling it and also dismantling every \hbox, but it's really complicated.
It's easier to typeset the box twice: the first time we set the boxes to their natural width. Now we can use the width of the created \vbox and repeat the setting with \hrulefill added to the material.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\stackhboxes}{m}
 {
  \filip_stackhboxes:n {#1}
 }

\box_new:N \l__filip_stackhboxes_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \filip_stackhboxes:n
 {
  % set the boxes at their natural width
  \vbox_set:Nn \l__filip_stackhboxes_box
   {
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { \hbox:n {##1} }
   }
  % rebuild the boxes and print
  \leavevmode
  \vbox:n
   {
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#1}
     {
      \hbox_to_wd:nn { \box_wd:N \l__filip_stackhboxes_box } {##1\hrulefill}
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some \stackhboxes{{longer text above}{shorter text}} and some more text.

\end{document}


This supports any number of boxes:
\stackhboxes{{<box 1>}{<box 2>}...{<box n>}}

You can also use spaces
\stackhboxes{
  {<box 1>}
  {<box 2>}
  ...
  {<box n>}
}

for better clarity. For instance
Some
\stackhboxes{
  {longer text above}
  {shorter text}
}
and some more text.

would typeset the same.

You should use a tabular here its "unset boxes" are exactly what you want, they finally all get set to the width of the widest box in a column.
You can suppress the extra padding by using
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
